# Disabling password login with ActiveAdmin/Devise and only allow Google OAuth login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

Like the title said, I am building an internal dashboard using ActiveAdmin at our company.

Recently, there has been a requirement that requires me to disable username/password login and only allow Google OAuth Login due to security issues.

I have successfully configured Google OAuth Login with Omniauth and Devise. How ever I cannot find any documentation on how to disable Username/Password Login

Comment: Can you not just remove those options from the form? I don't think you need to explicitly disable it if you don't present the user any option to go through that route.

Comment: Yeah, I have successfully remove the html form. But I can still retrieve session_id if I go the right route. Any way to override that?